# Finding for a specific row in a 2D Array and printing it out in Java

Tags: java

Sorry, I'm new to Java. I created a 2D array and populated it with String data. Now the task is to find a specific row in that array, that is filled with certain String and print it out. I mean to print only the row that was found. The problem is I don't know what row would it be. I managed to find that row and print it, but it prints the column along with the found row. Is it possible to print only the row but not the column? 
Sorry for my English.

```
public class Math extends StudentCharts {

public Math(){

math = new String [3][3];

math[0][0]="math";      math[0][1]="person1";    math[0][2]="49";   
math[1][0]=math[0][0];  math[1][1]="person2";    math[1][2]="12";   
math[2][0]=math[0][0];  math[2][1]="person3";    math[2][2]="31";  
}

public void prnt (String namechk){
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    for (x=0; x<3; x++) {
       if (namechk.equals(math[x][1])) {
           for (y=0; y<3; y++) {
        System.out.println(math[x][y]+" ");
    }
       }
       else { System.out.println("error");
    }
```

The main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Math chr1 = new Math();

    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter full name, please");
    String namecheck = user.nextLine();

    chr1.prnt(namecheck);
```

Comment: Could you add an example of the desired output?

Comment: It prints the row. But you use "println" rather than "print". Then it prints the elements below each other, as if it's a column.

Comment: The "else" branch causes the text "error" to be printed a few times. Not sure if this is intended. You may want to break from the loop after finding the value. You may also want to only print "error" if nothing is found. In that case, use a boolean variable that goes to `true` if something is found. And check it after the loop; if it is still `false` you'd print "error".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, the goal is to print the row if input matches the name in column 1 (for exampe I input "person1" and it prints: "math", "person1", "49"). If nothing is found it prints "error". My .equals statement works and i am able to make it print the correct row. But since i don't know the number of the row (because user can enter any name from an array) i can't identify it in the square brakets [?][1] to print only the intended row. Hope you can understand my language. Thank you very much.